# Change current URL then load

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, url, slice

I want jquery to find and change the current URL you are visiting and load the new one. Lets say jquery is supposed to change the current "index.html" to "indexalt.html" on click and then load it. My idea is to use document.URL to get the current URL then slice off ".html" at the end and add for example "alt.html" to string. I'm very new to jquery and don't get it to work. There will be a lot of mistakes within my script probably:

```
$("#contact").on('click', function() {
var url=document.URL(str.slice(-7));
.load("url +"alt.html"");
```

I would really appreciate if anyone can tell me how to do it and how to write it down correctly in a whole. Thanks!

Comment: `window.location = window.location.slice(0,-5) + 'alt.html'`

Comment: document.URL ???

Answer (score 0):

`location.href` returns the URL of the page. So, you can do this instead.

```
$("#contact").on("click", function() {
    // Slicing 5 characters from the URL.
    const url = location.href.slice(0, -5)
    // Simply load the URL
    location.href = url + "alt.html"
})
```